# paginate_all_by_something not workingi in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm upgrading my project to rails 3.0.1  , i have used paginate_all_by_something in the controller in rails 2.1.1 and rails 2.3.8 working fine but in rails 3.0.1 it displaying the undefined method `paginate_all_by_receiver_deleted' for #

error like this

If anybody faced like this problem kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of backwards incompatibility of new version of will_paginate (~>3.0).
Read [here](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Backwards-incompatibility) for further details.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Did any alias method is there for paginate_all_by_something in will paginate 3.0? Did anybody got the same type of issue while using will paginate in rails 3 version . Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use paginate on collections instead like this:

```
User.find_all_by_receiver( receiver_id ).paginate
```

So it's up to you how you construct the collections.